# Improve Camera preview in Object detection demo from Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera

I ran the object detection demo from Tensorflow for android and I noticed that the `DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE` in the `DetectorActivity` is static (640X480) and doesn't depend on the device screen size. When I changed that using these :

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

i noticed that with a bigger preview the detection got slower and preview is a little bit laggy when you move the phone. The problem is when I keep the 640x480 resolution and take a picture it's going to be too small. That's why I need a bigger preview size.

Any suggestions on how I can improve the speed of the camera preview with a dynamic size that suits phones with big screens? I thought of applying detection only on 1 of 2 frames for example to speed it up but apparently it won't work since the accuracy will drop...

Comment: That's a good question! Unfortunately I don't know the right way to deal with differing preview and final picture sizes, but I would investigate if there is a way to take your final photo at a different size than the preview, rather than altering the preview size.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. I'll give it a try and I'll post my results afterwards ! one other quick question .. why do we need to convert every Frame from YUV420SP to ARGB8888 before processing it ? doesn't that affect the inference time ? I created an other stackoverflow issue about it here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720286/why-tensorflow-object-detection-api-uses-yuv420sp-to-argb8888-conversion)

Comment: @user007 Did you find any solution?

Comment: @PeteWarden any solution?

Comment: @praj i totally forgot about this, and didn't post my results. I followed the tip from Pete and i got good results. The solution have the nothing to do with Tensorflow but with the camera itself. You need to figure out a way to set the preview at small resolution and take a photo in an other.

Comment: @user007 any code will help me lot.

Comment: @user007 Can you please provide an answer? It seems that there is a lot of people that have this issue.

Comment: @HB. i'm sorry i can't post the code since the project i was working on is not open source and i'm not allowed to share code snippets from it.

Comment: @user007 I did not ask for code. An explanation  has nothing to do with open source.

Comment: I ament able to comment but this post helped solve it for me:<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242648/screen-size-of-the-camera-on-the-example-object-detection-of-tensorflow-lite>