# Why Tensorflow object detection API uses YUV420SP to ARGB8888 conversion

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera, image-conversion

So I got the `tensorflow object detection API` running on Android and I've noticed while going through the code that before processing frames taken from the camera they're is a conversion that goes like this in the `CameraActivity.java` :

```
    imageConverter =
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageUtils.convertYUV420SPToARGB8888(bytes, previewWidth, previewHeight, rgbBytes);
                }
            };
```

I tried to look it up and I only understood the difference between the two types but I couldn't figure why this conversion is necessary (or preferable)..

Is this conversion since it's happening in real time and for every frame going to affect the preview or the processing time ?

Any information or explanation is much appreciated even if it's basic