# Screen Size of the camera on the example object detection of tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, camera, size, tensorflow-lite

On the tensorflow lite example object detection, the camera don't take all the screen but just a part.

I tried to find some constant in CameraActivity, CameraConnectionFragment and Size classes but no results.

So I just want a way to put the camera in all the screen or just an explanation.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

I just find the solution, it's in the CameraConnectionFragment class :
protected static Size chooseOptimalSize(final Size[] choices, final int width, final int height) {
    final int minSize = Math.max(Math.min(width, height), MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE);
    final Size desiredSize = new Size(1280, 720);

```
protected static Size chooseOptimalSize(final Size[] choices, final int width, final int height) {
final int minSize = Math.max(Math.min(width, height), MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE);
final Size desiredSize = new Size(1280, 720);

// Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
boolean exactSizeFound = false;
final List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
final List<Size> tooSmall = new ArrayList<Size>();
for (final Size option : choices) {
  if (option.equals(desiredSize)) {
    // Set the size but don't return yet so that remaining sizes will still be logged.
    exactSizeFound = true;
  }

  if (option.getHeight() >= minSize && option.getWidth() >= minSize) {
    bigEnough.add(option);
  } else {
    tooSmall.add(option);
  }
}
```

just replace 1280, 720 by what we want.

Comment: If you put different sizes, the image gets distorted.

Comment: I'm using the latest version for the TFLite object detection example, and it doesn't seem to contain this code. Any idea where I would specify the camera resolution in the current code structure? https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android