# Screen Size of the camera on the example object detection of tensorflow lite [Horizontal Screen]

Tags: android, tensorflow, camera, size, tensorflow-lite

On the tensorflow lite example object detection, the camera don't take all the screen but just a part.

I tried to find some constant in CameraActivity, CameraConnectionFragment and Size classes but no results.

So I just want a way to put the camera in all the screen or just an explanation.

By referring this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242648/screen-size-of-the-camera-on-the-example-object-detection-of-tensorflow-lite) link. It works perfectly on portrait screen but when I changed it into horizontal screen from manifest.xml . My horizontal camera screen is not fully covered. Please help. Thank you

Comment: All the information needed to answer should be contained in the question itself. You should consider updating the question with all that is relevant from the link, and leave the link in case someone wants to take a look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.